# Storing image file to SQL Server using php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a column called personal image with `image` data type.

I want to insert or update this field using PHP `sqlsrv` extension.

I have that image file for update query and i try this but the image not inserted correctly.

```
function prepareImageDBString($filepath)
{
    $out = 'null';
    $handle = @fopen($filepath, 'rb');
    if ($handle)
    {
        $content = @fread($handle, filesize($filepath));
        $content = bin2hex($content);
        @fclose($handle);
        $out = "0x".$content;
    }
    return $out;
}

$out = prepareImageDBString('871190915.jpg');

$update = "UPDATE Person SET PersonelImage=(?) WHERE no=871190915";
$image1=array($out);
sqlsrv_query($conn, $update, $image1);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to check for errors using using sqlsrv_errors (http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) after you execute your sqlsrv_query?

Comment: @becquerel there is no error found with sqlsrv_errors

Comment: Ok. And the Person exists where no is 871190915? (just want to double check). Also - "no" is a reserved word in MySQL, so it may also help to put `no` instead - but that may not solve the issue in hand.